# Dual Monitors Black Border

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I followed [a guide](http://goo.gl/ycYXQm) to set up a HP Pavilion DV6000 laptop with a Samsung SyncMaster 712N monitor via VGA as dual monitors side by side. Both resolutions are set to 1024 x 768 (ratio 4:3), but the laptop's screen has a black border on the sides. I would like to have the image on the whole screen.

The laptop's native resolution is 1280x800 (ratio 16:10) and the external's monitor native resolution is 1280x1024 (ratio 4:3). `lspci | grep VGA` says:

> Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop screen has adjusted to match the shape of the television.  Because its mirroring it has to do this or else it would look weird on the tv instead.  Since sometimes TVs are used for presentations or other business projects it matchs the TVs shape not the computer screen's.

Comment: My screens aren't set up to mirror each other it is set up to be side by side with different screens

Comment: A2: Well then if its on the sides try lowering the res on the monitor thats not working. If it were on the top and bottom you would have to rase the res.